# setting up a locally shared folder on Archlinux (on a ext4 filesystem)

Tags: linux, security, permissions, filesystems, arch-linux

Let's assume the following scenario. We have two users *trusted* and *untrusted*. User *untrusted* is used to access the internet and download data, which then has to be reviewed and given to user *trusted*. What I do so far is download data through the *untrusted* account, log in as *root* and review the data and then move the reviewed data to *trusted* and set the permissions of the data files to `trusted:users`. However this is a rather time-consuming process and I want to speed it up. So I created a shared folder as *root* with the following commands:

```
mkdir /srv/shared
chgrp users /srv/shared
chmod g+w,o-rx /srv/shared
setfacl -m d:g:users:rwx /srv/shared
```

With this both *trusted* and *untrusted* can create, read, write, delete and move files to and from this directory. I didn't test script execution but I think I won't need it, because anything inside that folder should be regarded as potentially hazardous.

Unfortunately I noticed that if *untrusted* creates a file in that folder and *trusted* uses

```
mv -i /srv/shared/created.by.untrusted ~
```

The user *trusted* ends up with the file created.by.untrusted in his home directory which is still owned by *untrusted*. The user *trusted* can edit and delete that file but he can't change the ownership to `trusted:users`. Is this a potential security hazard? Is there a way to change the ownership to `trusted:users` without using the *root* account? I was thinking about creating a new partition with the NTFS file system and mount it on /srv/shared in order to circumvent this problem. Files created there should have no permanent owner. But the problem with this approach is that the partition size would have to be limited by a fixed amount. In any case such an approach seems like "overkill" to me. Is there another way?

Comment: This may be better suited for the information security stack exchange.

Answer (score 0):

To my mind, Linux access policy does not allow for unpriviledged users to change ownership of files without change of i-node. These operations are moving, renaming and editing. When copying you change i-node as if you create new file with default ownership. Therefore, just copy `created.by.untrusted` file to the home dir of user `trusted`, and delete the original file :).

Then, if you so fear of copied files, just block access to the folder where you are intended to store these files from untrusted users, or make them unreadable for them.

Comment: Do you know whether there are any pseudo-filesystems that would allow me to ignore file and owner permissions? I was thinking about something like `vboxsf` from Virtualbox: `mount -t vboxsf foo /srv/shared`.